# How do I populate individual dates using addDays() onto a series of child records?

Tags: date, after-trigger, individual, parent-to-child, days

To give you some context, I'm writing a trigger between a parent-child relationship ("Event" - "Day"). When entering number of days into the Event__c object, I would like to populate a series of Day__c records corresponding to that number and populating the individual dates onto said Day__c records.

I am able to populate a series of Day__c records, but get the following error when I enter line 11 below: *Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void addDays(Integer) from the type PopulateDays*

*Date__c* and *Event_Date__c* are both Date data types.

```
trigger PopulateDays on Event__c (after insert, after update) {
        List<Day__c> insertDays = New List<Day__c>();
        
        if (Trigger.IsInsert || Trigger.IsUpdate) {
            for (Event__c ev : Trigger.new) {
                if (ev.Number_of_Days__c != null) {
                    for (integer i = 0; i < ev.Number_of_Days__c; i++) {
                        Day__c day = New Day__c();
                        day.Event__c = ev.Id;
                        day.Name = 'Day ' + (i + 1);
                        day.Date__c = ev.Event_Date__c + addDays(i);
                        insertDays.add(day);
                    }
                }
                try {
                    if (!insertDays.IsEmpty()) {
                        insert insertDays;
                    }
                }
                catch (exception e) {
                    System.debug(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
day.Date__c = ev.Event_Date__c + addDays(i);
```

Should be

```
day.Date__c = ev.Event_Date__c.addDays(i);
```

or, since Event_Date__c could be null; use the Safe Navigation Operator introduced in V50

```
day.Date__c = ev.Event_Date__c?.addDays(i);
```

As an aside, you don't need to do this:

```
if (!insertDays.IsEmpty()) {
                    insert insertDays;
                }
```

as

```
 insert insertDays;
```

works just fine, even if list is empty and does not burn a DML statement.

Final Pro Tip -- you should not be eating an insert exception. Use `addError()` method on the relevant `Trigger.New` record(s)

Comment: Thank you for this. Was on this awhile and can't believe I didn't catch that.